# How do I get the house element of a column by hover?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a bar chart and want to get the house targeted, how can I do that?
`enter code here` https://jsfiddle.net/yz1Lcedk/13/

Comment: Hi @Иван Кондратьев, What do you mean by `the house targeted`? You can for example get the hovered graphic element in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h5Ldxw6v/

Comment: I want to get the house element of the column by hovering

Comment: Do you mean the SVG element in HTML DOM? This will be: `this.graphic.element` in the event function callback.